# A2212 1000kv Brushless motor keep beeping and twitching

Tags: esc, brushless-motors, lipo-batteries, propellers, battery-discharge-rating

I have bought an A2212 1000Kv brushless motor and a 30A ESC. I power this setup with a 7.4v 2s 30c 800mah LiPo battery. For the signal, I am using a DIY Arduino receiver and transmitter. When I test the motor with a test code(linked below) and without the propeller(10x4.5) it runs fine. But with the propeller on it, it makes a booting sound and then, beeeeep beep, beeeep beep beep. These beeps are not constant rapid beeps and it just keeps looping these sounds. Sometimes if I'm lucky, the motor will start and then after a second it shuts off and reboots and does not work again. *what I have found is that the motor cuts of at around 60% throttle.

I have spares of these two items and I have the same problem with them.
These motors are new and I have personally never seen them run with propellers, only without propellers.

How do I fix my motor?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming stable power to the ESC, it's probably an issue with comms between the FC and the ESC. Sounds like they're rebooting. Check protocol, wiring, etc.

Comment: Sorry what is FC?

Comment: Flight controller

Answer (score 0):

That's a pretty small battery for a large motor and prop. I'd guess that the motor can't provide the current the motor needs.

Without the prop, the motor draws very little current but when you add the prop, the chemical reaction in the battery can't happen fast enough and the voltage sags. When the voltage sags far enough, the ESC (or Arduino) stops running. That allows the battery to recover, and the cycle repeats.

You can check this by monitoring the battery voltage. It's worth getting a wattmeter so you can measure the current too, and ensure you're not pushing your components past their limits. They're available from about $20

If this is the problem, the solution is a bigger battery or a smaller prop. If you have two batteries, you could connect them in parallel so they act like a bigger battery.